# Is there a pre-processor variable indicating QNX SDP 6/7 difference?

Tags: c-preprocessor, qnx-neutrino, version-detection

We have some code originally developed for QNX SDP 6.6 that we are porting to QNX SDP 7.0 (7.1 does not yet have the board support packages we need).

As part of the porting effort, we are finding things that have been removed in 7.1, such as `getprio()` to retrieve the process priority. Now I know what that need to be replaced with but, in the interest of minimal impact to the code base, I went looking for a pre-processor variable to indicate whether I'm compiling with SDP 7.0 or something earlier.

That way, I could simply use `#ifdef` to select which code to compile, along the lines of `__STDC_VERSION__` to figure out which ISO iteration applies.

However, I can't find *anything* in the QNX docs that seem relevant. I found `__QNX__` and `__QNXNTO__` which together let me figure out whether it's non-QNX, QNX 4, or QNX Neutrino, but nothing that appears to detect a difference between QNX 6 and 7.

Is there such a beast available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears [there is a preprocessor macro for it.](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/)

Specifically, you include `<sys/neutrino.h>` for QNX 6.6 or 7.0, or `<sys/nto_version.h>` for QNX 7.1. I don't have access to others but would expect the scheme to continue.

You can then test `_NTO_VERSION` which is defined as `VRR`, where `V` is the major version and `RR` is the revision.

The following transcript shows the relevant header file content:

```bash
Cmd> cd ~/qnx_inst
Cmd> rgrep '#define _NTO_VERSION' | grep -v 'Binary file'
qnx660/target/qnx6/usr/include/sys/neutrino.h:#define _NTO_VERSION  660     /* version number * 100 */
qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include/sys/neutrino.h:#define _NTO_VERSION  700     /* version number * 100 */
qnx710/target/qnx7/usr/include/sys/nto_version.h:#define _NTO_VERSION       710     /* version number * 100 */
```

Comment: Awesome, works for all of 6.6, 7.0, and 7.1, which are the ones I have installed.